# Importing values in config.py

Tags: python, config, configparser

I wanted to mix a config.py approach and ConfigParser to set some default values in config.py which could be overridden by the user in its root folder:

```
import ConfigParser
import os

CACHE_FOLDER = 'cache'
CSV_FOLDER = 'csv'

def main():
    cp = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    cp.readfp(open('defaults.cfg'))
    cp.read(os.path.expanduser('~/.python-tools.cfg'))
    CACHE_FOLDER = cp.get('folders', 'cache_folder')
    CSV_FOLDER = cp.get('folders', 'csv_folder')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running this module I can see the value of CACHE_FOLDER being changed. However when in another module I do the following:

```
import config

def main()
    print config.CACHE_FOLDER
```

This will print the original value of the variable ('cache').

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` function in the code you show only gets run when that module is run as a script (due to the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block). If you want that turn run any time the module is loaded, you should get rid of that restriction. If there's extra code that actually does something useful in the `main` function, in addition to setting up the configuration, you might want to split that part out from the setup code:

```
def setup():
    # the configuration stuff from main in the question

def main():
    # other stuff to be done when run as a script

setup()  # called unconditionally, so it will run if you import this module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  # this is called only when the module is run as a script
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood I thought that main() would be called unconditionally and the part after the if would be only run in script. Thanks.